# Way to keep subversion global revision number in a file?

Tags: svn

searching around, this seems to be an often asked question, but I couldn't find a proper way of doing it yet. Basically I want every time I commit some changes to my project to be able to update a file with the global revision number. The idea is to output this global revision number when running the code (the users of my code sometimes use old revisions and if some problem or strange behaviour in the code is found, I can use this global revision number to know exactly which version of the code they were running).

I know about svnversion, but this is no good, because this will tell me the revision number of my current working version. Say I'm working on revision 100 and I make some changes (svnversion would tell me 100M). If in the meantime other developers have been committing many changes, but the time I commit my version, this might be revision 120. If I were to use the output from svnversion this would be misleading, I would like to keep the exact revision number committed (i.e. 120).

One way I can think of doing this (though I have seen many people complaining that it would be abusing subversion) is to have a rev.h file or similar, which I make sure I commit for every commit, and which it simply has code for keyword substituting $Rev$. If I force to commit it for every single 'real' commit, then it will always have the global revision number at the time of committing. The problem with this approach is that it certainly does not look elegant and I don't know how to forcefully always commit this file without having to change it manually every time.

How can accomplish this automatic committing of an unmodified file? Otherwise, any other ideas on how to keep in the code the global revision number (but the one at the time of committing, not of the working version)?

Many thanks,
Ángel de Vicente

Comment: Perhaps you can implement your ideas in code and post it here so that we can assist you by correcting it.

Comment: Well, my hope is not to need to code anything. Ideally (assuming there is no better way to get the global revision number) I would like to be able to set some property for a file that just says to subversion: "commit this file always, pretend that it was modified".

Comment: SVN maintains a "global" revision across a repository . so when you commit a change  the revision number you get is "global" .
eg: try updating  your working copy . 

svn up
Updating '.':
At revision 83205.

here 83205 is the global revision .

Comment: @born, yes, I know that a 'global' revision number is kept, and that is precisely what I want, to be able to include automatically that global revision number into one of the files of my project. Keyword substitution of $Rev$ only says in which revision that particular file was changed. I want to somehow tell Subversion to include the global revision number into one of my files when doing a checkout, but I don't know how....

Comment: I found this old thread about this issue, but apparently no easy way of doing it. http://subversion.1072662.n5.nabble.com/Any-simple-way-to-set-get-global-revision-number-td134624.html

Comment: Ok . I use Apache Ant and some java code to do the same thing. There's this utility called  svnAnt http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant.html , very use full if your environment permits it . But you are right there is not easy way do doing it. you have to come up with some kind of hacks .

Comment: I guess I will just try to convince our users to do something like this:  svn co .... ; svnversion > version.h    I know it is not ideal, users can change the code before compiling it, etc. but assuming they cooperate, having this information at built time I will be able at least to see which revision they checked out. Cheers